# CvBridge conversion problem: Asus Xtion depth image to OpenCV

Tags: ros, opencv, xtion, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a Asus Xtion sensor being driven by the Openni2_launch package. I subscribe to the "/camera/depth/image" topic and attempt to convert the ImageConstPtr& data type to an OpenCV Mat in a callback function utilising the cv_bridge package. Visualising the "/camera/depth/image" ROS topic in RQT, I get a high quality depth image as expected:

[image: image description]

However I can't seem to find an image type encoding (e.g. "8UC1") which OpenCV/cv_bridge accepts which results in an image similar to the one above. As an example, with the encoding "32FC1", this is the type of quality I get. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong!

[image: image description]

And here's the source code

```
// Callback function for time-synchronised RGB and depth images
void sync_callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& rgb, const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& depth)
{
    // Convert ROS images to OpenCV
    cv::Mat rgb_image;
    cv::Mat depth_image;

    try
    {
        rgb_image = cv_bridge::toCvShare(rgb, "mono8") -> image;
        depth_image = cv_bridge::toCvShare(depth, "32FC1") -> image;
    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
        ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from ROS images to OpenCV type: %s", e.what());
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212747/cvbridge-conversion-problem:-asus-xtion-depth-image-to-opencv/) by [WillAndrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/22907/willandrew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-07-02

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output from openni2_camera is 32FC1, with measurements in meters. In the past I have converted to 32FC1, and then normalized in the range of ~0.5m to 5.5m. I haven't tried to compile my [depth_viewer](https://github.com/mikeferguson/sandbox/blob/hydro-devel/depth_viewer/src/depth_viewer.cpp) in a while, but it is probably a good starting spot.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2015-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WillAndrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/22907/willandrew/) on 2015-07-06**:
Works really well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should works.

```
void sync_callback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& rgb, const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& depth)
{
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr depthImg = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(depth , sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1);

    //Normalize the pixel value
    cv::normalize(depthImg->image, depthImg->image, 1, 0, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    
    imwrite("./depth.jpg", depthImg->image);
    ros::shutdown();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-07-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-07-03**:
My Xtion gives me a 16bpp image, so I would use 16UC1.

**Comment by [WillAndrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/22907/willandrew/) on 2015-07-03**:
Thanks! but both of your suggestions didn't work (32FC1 resulted in the same black&white image, 16UC1 was just completely black..)

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-03**:
Thx, I used 32FC1 for Kinect. But it's weird it cannot show properly.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2015-07-03**:
Sorry I have to correct myself, 16UC1 is for image_raw, what does

```
rostopic echo /camera/depth/image --noarr
```

report for you?

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-03**:
My Kinect is borrowed from someone now, so I don't have one to test.

**Comment by [WillAndrew](https://answers.ros.org/users/22907/willandrew/) on 2015-07-06**:
"encoding: 32FC1" for the Xtion